# A question about estimating unobserved states in MARSS package in R

Tags: r

I am working on a state space model in R using the MARSS package. The following is the code

```
rm(list=ls())
cls <- function() cat(rep("\n",1000))
cls()

library(MARSS)
library(moments)
library(fGarch)
library(copula)
library(VineCopula)
library(maxLik)
library(sn)

dat=read.csv("F://potential_output/italy.csv",header=T)
summary(dat)




# transpose data so time goes across columns
dat = t(dat)
# get number of time series
N = dim(dat)[1]
# get length of time series
TT = dim(dat)[2]

Z.vals=list(1, "z1", 0, "z2", 0, 0, 0, "z3",
           0, "z4",     0,    0,     0, 0, 0, 0,
           "z5", "z6",  "z7", "z8", 0, 0, "z9", 0,
           0, 0,     0,   "z10",      0, 0,  0,0,
           "z11", 0,  "z12",  0, "z13", "z14", 0, 0,
           0, 0,     0,   0,      0, "z15", 0, 0,
           0, 0,     0,   0,      0, 0, "z16", 0,
           0, 0,     0,   0,      0, 0, 0, "z17")


Z=matrix(Z.vals,nrow=N,ncol=N,byrow=T)



#R.vals=list("b1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b2", 0,
           0, "b3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, "b4", 0, 0, 0,"b5","b6",
           0, 0, 0, "b7", 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, "b8", "b9", 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b10", 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b11", 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b12")

#R=matrix(R.vals,nrow=N,ncol=N,byrow=T)


B.vals=list("b1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b2", 0,
           0, "b3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, "b4", 0, 0, 0,"b5","b6",
           0, 0, 0, "b7", 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, "b8", "b9", 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b10", 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b11", 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "b12")

B=matrix(B.vals,nrow=N,ncol=N,byrow=T)

U=matrix(list(0), nrow=N, ncol=1, byrow=T)
A=matrix(list(0), nrow=N, ncol=1, byrow=T)

#Q=B=diag(1,2)

x0=U #matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=1)
x0=A=U="zero"
#V0=diag(8,2)

dfa.model = list(Z=Z, A=A, B=B, U=U)
cntl.list = list(maxit=500)
model.2 = MARSS(dat, model=dfa.model)
```

I want to see the estimated states. So i typed print(MLEobj,what="xtT"). But this produced the observables i.e the data and not the estimated states. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? How can i find out the estimated state variables?

Thanks, Looking forward.

Comment: Can anyone please look at the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
print(MLEobj,what="xtT")
```

does print the smoothed states. However if your estimated R is 0, then the estimated states will equal the data (if n=m).

Note if you are using the current version of MARSS,

```
plot(MLEobj)
```

will run through some example plot (including the states).

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the code, I did not mention the structure of R. So by default R should take 'diagonal and equal'. Then how do I control R. Why is R=0?

Comment: You didn't show the model fit, i.e. `coef(fit)`, so I'm just guessing that the MLE estimate of R is R=0. Yes, it is specified a 'diagonal and equal' and R all zero is 'diagonal and equal'. That is the only thing that would cause the states estimate (xtT) to be equal to the data.  Without seeing your data and model, I can't say why R=0 (if it does). That's not an error; it's just the MLE R for your data and model. That said, an MLE of R=0 can be caused by trying to fit a model that is incompatible with your data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! My data contains lagged dependent variables. Could that be the reason of R coming out to be zero? How can I post the data and model here?

Comment: I am getting these warnings - 21 warnings.
 iter=51 Setting element of Q to 0, blocked due to the following MARSSkemcheck errors.
  MARSSkemcheck error: One of the diagonal elements of Sigma[,,1]=0. That should never happen when t>1 or t=1 and tinitx=0.  
 Are both Q[i,i] and R[i,i] being set to 0?
 iter=51 Setting element of Q to 0, blocked due to the following MARSSkemcheck errors.
  MARSSkemcheck error: One of the diagonal elements of Sigma[,,1]=0. That should never happen when t>1 or t=1 and tinitx=0.  
 Are both Q[i,i] and R[i,i] being set to 0?

Comment: The warning is alerting you that it is trying to set Q to 0 and the error-checking is blocking that probably after R was set to 0. Pass in `control=list(allow.degen=FALSE)` to prevent degenerate models (degenerate means R or Q equal to 0).   Regarding why R is going to 0, there are many reasons this can happen. It is not an error. It means that the max likelihood model has R=0.